# Calculate how big (byte size) a string will be if it were gzipped?

Tags: c#, .net, gzip

Is there any way to calculate how big a string would become if it were gzipped, without actually gzipping it? The calculated value doesn't have to be 100% accurate.

If there isn't a way to calculate the size and you have to actually gzip it and look at the byte size, is this operation CPU intensive? The strings (not gzipped) are around 200-500kb.

Comment: You would likely go through almost all the steps of the actual compression code, so likely you won't gain anything here. However, if the strings are somewhat related, like all strings are source code (or pieces of such), or all strings is from english text, then you may be able to get some numbers by just using statistics, ie. just compress one string and use it as a factor, or compress a huge list of strings and generate a min/max ratio. This assumes that all your strings have comparable compression ratios.

Comment: To better such statistics you could track the ratio compared to initial size, and gather a lot of these ratio numbers and use methods such as monte carlo simulation to get a set of values with probabilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to calculate that is to actually gzip it.  There is no calculation that would take less CPU time.  It might take a smidge less real time if you don't write the result to mass storage.